# Why do I need to export the component to pass it to the registerComponent method?

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

This code works fine:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello World!</Text>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => App);
```

But I get the error when I do not export the App component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello World!</Text>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => App);
```

Why do I need to export the `App` component to pass it to the `registerComponent` method? Is this because `AppRegistry.registerComponent` is not inside the `App` class component? Do I need to export class components even if there were in the same file?

Here is the error I get in the iOS simulator:
*I use expo.

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `ExpoRootComponent`.

This error is located at:
    in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:34)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:33)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:32)

throwOnInvalidElementType
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:4705:2
createFiberFromElement
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:4663:16
reconcileSingleElement
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8337:22
reconcileChildFibers
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8421:12
reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8621:29
finishClassComponent
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8839:4
updateClassComponent
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8761:11
beginWork
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:9580:15
performUnitOfWork
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12924:15
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: How are you importing the module?

Comment: Also fix `’SampleApp'` into `'SampleApp'`

Comment: I added the error message to my post. Also, typos are fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Something needs to be exported in order for it to be imported later on by some other script.

According to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

> The export statement is used when creating JavaScript modules to export functions, objects, or primitive values from the module so they can be used by other programs with the import statement.

My guess is the registerComponent method expects a module as one of the parameters.